# How to disable interaction styling completely?

Tags: openlayers-3

Is it possible to disable interaction styling completely? I've tried to set it to null, but it doesn't work. And seems like interaction style function is not used when style is assigned to features, but not layer?

```
this.hoverInteraction = new ol.interaction.Select ({
    condition : ol.events.condition.pointerMove,
    layers : this.layers,
    style  : function () { // is not called?
        console.log ('check');
    },
    multi : false
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Should be able to keep styles from showing if you just pass an empty array:

```
new ol.interaction.Select({
  condition: ol.events.condition.pointerMove,
  style: []
});
```

I have a feeling your issue might be the `layers : this.layers` part, `this` is probably not referring to what you want here.

Comment: Doesn't work, unfortunately... )-: About "this" - no, it is ok. The problem is: I have feature with icon and I need hover and click interaction. Feature layer is of type ol.layer.Image. When I mouseover feature and zoom quickly at the same time, I see two icon images - one raster icon of ol.layer.Image layer and one vector icon of (as I understand) interaction overlay. I've made a [screenshot of the problem](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/33755813/problem.png)